# Return Multiple Values From javascript function giving Error in Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

What I want to do is that I need to create markers from stored location of user. So for that I need latitude and longitude. I got the lat & lon in my function get_current_user_lat_lon . Now I want to return both lat & lon through Object but my return is not working....

```
function initialize(){
    var var_get_current_user_lat_lon = get_current_user_lat_lon(); 
    var latitutde = var_get_current_user_lat_lon.latitutde;
    alert(latitutde);// not even alert
    var longitutde = var_get_current_user_lat_lon.longitutde;
    alert(longitutde); // not even alert
}        

function get_current_user_lat_lon(){
    var address = $("#hidden_current_location").val();//Working fine
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var variable = results[0].geometry.location;
            var lat  = variable.lat();
            var lon  = variable.lng();
            alert(lat); //Working fine
            alert(lon); //Working fine
            //return not working here
        }
        //return not working here
    });
    return {latitutde: lat , longitutde : lon};// giving error lat.lon is not defined means return not working here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "lat" and "lon" variables are declared **inside** the callback from "geocode()".  Even if you declared them outside it, however, the overall idea would not work.  The "geocode()" function is **asynchronous**; that's the reason there's a callback function in the first place.

Instead of structuring your code so that your "get_current_user_lat_lon()" function *returns* a value, follow the lead of the Google architecture and make your own function take a callback:

```
function get_current_user_lat_lon( callback ){
  var address = $("#hidden_current_location").val();//Working fine
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var variable = results[0].geometry.location;
        var lat  = variable.lat();
        var lon  = variable.lng();
        callback({latitude: lat, longitude: lon});
      }

  });

}
```

Comment: so what to do now ??shall i go to do file_get_contents(googlemaps etc etc) docodeing n etc....

Comment: Yes - you have to do the things you need to do after the geocoding returns from *inside* the callback function.